# Flex 4 for Flex 3 developers - Layout Issues

Tags: apache-flex, layout, flex4, flex3

I've read a lot of articles saying that in order to use the old "Layout='Absolute'" in Flex 4, I simply have to use

```
<s:layout>
    <s:BasicLayout/>
</s:layout>
```

But it just doesn't work the same way. On Flex 3, when you set your application layout as absolute, the X and Y properties automatically lose their utility since every component of your layout will be determined automatically by default in the top left of your screen. It works similarly as the mobile layouts: You either use Canvas to set X and Y (most used by mobile game developers) or you let the device to place everything so it will avoid screen size problems and such.

Is it still possible on Flex 4? How harder/complex is it?
Thanks for your attention.

Edit -------

So it seem a little bit confuse what I want. Back to Flex e, I used to do this:

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" creationComplete="onInit()" width="100%" height="100%"
```

I started my application with this tag and down there I would have a box container with 100% width and 100% height.
So, inside this box container I would have HBox and VBox to align my components (now VGroup and HGroup). The thing is that in Flex 3 I could place 1 VBox, for instance, and 3 HBox inside it that each HBox would assume a position automatically one under the other, that is with X and Y properties blank. With Flex 4, when I place 1 VGroup and 3 HGroup inside without setting any X and Y propert, they'll just fill up one above the other, like if I had set X,Y = 0 to all of them. They don't assume position one under the other like it used to.

Comment: Using layout="absolute" in Flex 3 will place components according to their x and y properties. So does <s:BasicLayout> in Flex 4.

Comment: Yeah, but in flex 3 if I don't set any x and y, they'll be placed in running time, which in Flex 4 BasicLayout doesn't work. If I don't set any X and Y, all components will be floating one inside the other.

Comment: What do you mean "placed in running time"? Please, tell, what do you want to do

Comment: I'm gonna edit the main post to try to clarify it better.

Comment: Guess you use new components (VGroup, HGroup) incorrect. Flex4 BasicLayout works absolutely same way as "layout=absolute" in Flex 3 - i have this in all my applications.

Comment: Could you provide me just a sample that works for you property? I mean, just a startApp with 1 BoxContainer, 1 VGroup and 3 HGroup inside the VGroup, each with one HelloWorld or whatever just so I can compare files and see if I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the Flex 3 to Flex 4 equivalent layouts in [Spark Layouts with Flex 4](http://www.adobemarketing.com/devnet/flex/articles/spark_layouts.html):

> Working with the Spark Layouts
>
> Because layouts and containers are separated in Spark, there are a few
>   notable changes that you need to take into account when working with
>   the layouts. Take a moment to examine the following table of MX layout
>   container classes and their corresponding combination of Spark layout
>   and container:
>
> ```
> MX Containers Corresponding combination of Spark Layout and Container
> Canvas        Group with BasicLayout (no advanced constraints)
> HBox          Group with HorizontalLayout (or the HGroup class)
> VBox          Group with VerticalLayout (or the VGroup class)
> Tile          Group with TileLayout
> List          List with VerticalLayout
> TileList      List with TileLayout
> ```

In your case, it sounds like you want a dynamic layout rather than an absolute one because you say you do not want to supply X and Y coordinates for your controls.

You then have two options:

- Use the BasicLayout and specify the top, left, right, bottom properties for your controls
- Use HorizontalLayout, VerticalLayout, or one of the other dynamic layouts.